# SQL Search doesn't find all values

Tags: mysql, select

I'm beginner in MySQL and I want to make a request to find all tables with this word "Ostéotomie", it works only if I write "%Ost%" and not "%Ostéotomie%"
The fact is that it shows me only 4 results instead of the 9 I need.

Here is a SQL Fiddle to show what I mean : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/295624/2)

The table wasn't created by me, I'm working on a search bar from a project which isn't mine.
I don't know if you can help me, if I've putted enough information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query is working as expected only if we keep `é` as `%`.

Comment: I'll try and see if it works !

Comment: @KévinHuang , Why there is different result set for **'%Ostéo%'** and **'%Osté%'** ?

Comment: @Alpesh Jikadra I don't know, that's what I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: @Neeraj Wadhwa Thanks it works fine ! How can I make it as resolved but for a comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replacing `é` with `%` and the query gave me expected results.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html

Maybe this solved your Problem.

Comment: @Neeraj Wadhwa answered to me, I would like him to write an answer and approve his answer, thanks for helping me though :)

Comment: Was just a thought that the latin could be the right answer ;)